# Extract all raster cells outside a polygon

Tags: qgis, raster, vector

How does one perform the very simple task of extracting all raster cell values outside a polygon? I've been looking through QGIS for hours with no solution to this simple problem.

Answer (score 3):

Idea how to make an outside clip:

- Make an Extent layer of your raster layer (Polygon from Layer-Extent in Vector Menu)
- Do a symetrical difference (also in Vector Menu) with your polygons
- Use the resulting layer in gdal to clip your raster layer (clipper in Raster menu)

Then you could just do your zonal statistics or whatever you want to do with the cell values.